# Number of critical points of a product

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose f, g are smooth functions with n and m local minima, respectively.  Can we put an upper bound, in terms of n and m on the number of local minima of the product fg? The example of f(x)=x, g(x)=ln(x) shows that n+m is insufficient, as neither of these functions has a local minimum, but the product h(x)=xln(x) has a unique local minimum.

Comment: This is answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337020/can-the-product-of-two-monotone-functions-have-more-than-one-turning-point

Comment: Hmmm very interesting.  Thanks for that.